# Spurious Google Fit 5015 error?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am reading GPS data from my Android Wear watch and then inserting into the Google Fit datastore using the Fitness.HistoryAPI. But **some** records are being rejected with 5015 errors, which apparently means:
`INCONSISTENT_PACKAGE_NAME

Status code denotes that app attempted to insert data for a DataSource that does not match the app's package name.`

So the dataSource is not custom, and afaict all the datasources are the same on all the records, but only some are being rejected.

See some logging information below:...

```
V: Data Source DataSource{raw:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2}::DataType{com.google.location.sample[latitude(f), longitude(f), accuracy(f), altitude(f)]}}: device Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2} and type: com.google.location.sample
V: Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found!  Registering.
V: DataPoint: Time=1466284820248, Source=DataSource{raw:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2}::DataType{com.google.location.sample[latitude(f), longitude(f), accuracy(f), altitude(f)]}}
V:  latitude = 37.28372
V:  longitude = -122.024345
V:  accuracy = 50.0
V:  altitude = unset
V: Recording...
V: DataPoint: Time=1466284823387, Source=DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2}:default:DataType{com.google.activity.sample[activity(i), confidence(f)]}}
V:  activity = 3
V:  confidence = 100.0
V: Recording...
V: DataPoint: Time=1466284826561, Source=DataSource{raw:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2}::DataType{com.google.location.sample[latitude(f), longitude(f), accuracy(f), altitude(f)]}}
V:  latitude = 37.28377
V:  longitude = -122.02438
V:  accuracy = 31.0
V:  altitude = 73.0
V: Recording...
V: DataPoint: Time=1466284861826, Source=DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2}:default:DataType{com.google.activity.sample[activity(i), confidence(f)]}}
V:  activity = 3
V:  confidence = 100.0
V: Recording...
D: Data sets number of points: Speed 0, Location 2, Activity 2
D: Failed to insert data type com.google.activity.sample for reason 5015 null
D: Checking inserted fitness data for com.google.location.sample in this period 1466284820000-1466284881000
D: Failed to insert data type com.google.location.sample for reason 5015 null
D: Successfully inserted Session Sat, Jun 18; 2:20PM: Period 1
D: Found 1 data points for data type com.google.location.sample
V: Timestamp        Latitude    Longitude   Altitude    Accuracy
V: 1466284826561    37.283772   -122.024384 73.000000   31.000000
```

So there were two location records found, both with the same dataSourcem but apparently one of them was rejected (as you can see the query found only one location record after the 5015 error).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find the reason for this problem (no help from Google yet either), but I did find a workaround by creating my own data sources with associated data sets, and then copying all data points from the built-in-data sources to my own data sets, and then inserting these.